# Comparing 2 xml files XmlElement using linq to xml

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to compare 2 xml files.

1. File1.xml
2. File2.xml

When I say compare I don't mean the structure, that is the same.
I only need to compare their values.

Given an Element Name loop through all the children and compare each value if are the same.

- I can easily loop through each element
- Get the same element from the other file and compare the value

Wondering if there is already an in built function to do this?

thanks for any suggestions